# New fixltx2e, bigfoot conflict?

Tags: texlive, incompatibility, bigfoot

After one of the more recent package updates, my book did not compile anymore under TexLive 2014. I narrowed the problem down to a new incompatibility between the packages `fixltx2e` and `bigfoot`. The following minimal example doesn't compile anymore and throws errors like

```
Missing number, treated as zero."
```

and

```
"Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)"
```

Not using one of the two packages makes it work again.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fixltx2e,bigfoot}

\begin{document}
Test\footnote{Test}
\end{document}
```

Can anybody help?

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
inputenc.sty    2014/04/30 v1.2b Input encoding file
    utf8.def    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
   t1enc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
  ot1enc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
  omsenc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
fixltx2e.sty    2014/08/30 v1.1s fixes to LaTeX
 bigfoot.sty    2006/07/15 1.25 makes footnotes work
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
manyfoot.sty    2005/09/11 v1.10 Many Footnote Levels Package (NCC)
nccfoots.sty    2005/02/03 v1.2 NCC Footnotes Package (NCC)
  suffix.sty    2006/07/15 1.5 Variant command support
 perpage.sty    2006/07/15 1.12 Reset/sort counters per page
```

Comment: I get no error. Can you add `\listfiles` to your example and report the output you find in the `.log` file after `*File List*`?

Comment: I can confirm the error for up-to-date TL 2014

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Sure thing, there you go: 
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h ...
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h ...
inputenc.sty    2014/04/30 v1.2b ...
    utf8.def    2008/04/05 v1.1m ...
   t1enc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m ...
  ot1enc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m ...
  omsenc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m ...
fixltx2e.sty    2014/08/30 v1.1s fixes to LaTeX
 bigfoot.sty    2006/07/15 1.25 ...
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 ...
manyfoot.sty    2005/09/11 v1.10 ..
nccfoots.sty    2005/02/03 v1.2 ...
  suffix.sty    2006/07/15 1.5 ...
 perpage.sty    2006/07/15 1.12 ...

Comment: @Thorsten Please, add it to your question, so it's easier to parse

Comment: @Thorsten Yes, now I can see the problem.

Comment: It is obviously a conflict of the \MakeSorted command of the perpage package with the new code in fixltx2e to reset all dependant counters. But it needs more digging to find out if and how one can avoid it.

Comment: `perpage` does not seem to like that`fixltx2e` redefines `\@stpelt`...

Comment: Would it be possible to draw the maintainers' attention to this? But maybe they're already thinking about a solution?

Comment: You could try to contact the author of perpage/bigfoot.

Comment: I would have done so, but cannot find a promising contact form, issue tracker, email address. DK seems to be cautious with his address.

Comment: @Thorsten The author has been notified. Currently I would suggest that you simply restore after the fixltx2e the `\@stpelt`definition: `\makeatletter 
\def\@stpelt#1{\global\csname c@#1\endcsname \z@}
\makeatother`

Comment: Can you check with the new `bigfoot` 2.0 released 2014/10/23? It was on today's update list for TeX Live.

Comment: I updated to the current TexLive version of bigfoot today - it works now again, for the minimal example as well as for my book! You guys rock! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue has been solved via update to package bigfoot. Thanks everyone!