# Why the new changes to LaTeX kernel breaks zref-perpage package?

Tags: latex-base, zref

Consider the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{zref-perpage}
\zmakeperpage{footnote}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\footnote{A footnote}
\footnote{A footnote}
\newpage
\footnote{Another footnote}
\end{document}
```

The desired effect is that the first footnote number in each page should be 1 however whenever there is a chapter on a page, the first footnote number on that page is 2.

I believe that new changes to LaTeX kernel somehow are to blame because the `zref` bundle have not been updated for few years. You also can confirm that this minimal example worked perfectly by using an online LaTeX compiler like overleaf which uses TeXLive 2014.

So far, I have found that adding another

```
\@addtoreset{footnote}{chapter}
```

fixes the problem so you should have at least two of this.

So what's wrong?

Comment: Thanks Heiko. Do you know what's wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `book` and `report` class reset the counter `footnote` at each numbered chapter:

```
\@addtoreset{footnote}{chapter}
```

The counter is applied to two systems, which reset it, thus `\zmakeperpage` does not have the full control over the counter. Since you want to have the counter reset at page boundaries, the effect of `\@addtoreset` must be undone. Here package `removefromreset` helps:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{remreset}
\makeatletter
\@removefromreset{footnote}{chapter}
\makeatother

\usepackage{zref-perpage}
\zmakeperpage{footnote}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\footnote{A footnote}
\footnote{A footnote}
\newpage
\footnote{Another footnote}
\end{document}
```

The responsible change in LaTeX 2015/01/01 is the changed definition of `\@stpelt`. After a `\@addtoreset{foo}{bar}` the master counter `bar` is increases, the dependent counters as `foo` are reset. Macro `\@stpelt` implements the reset. The old version just sets the counter to zero:

```
\def\@stpelt#1{\global\csname c@#1\endcsname \z@}
```

The new version sets first to -1 in order to use `\stepcounter`:

```
\def\@stpelt#1{\global\csname c@#1\endcsname \m@ne\stepcounter{#1}}
```

Advantage:

- The advantage is, that counter, which depend on the dependent counter are also reset. Example:

  ```
  ... previous section with sections, subsections, subsubsections ...
  \section % resets subsection
  ```

  In the old version of `\@stpelt`, counter `subsubsection` is unchanged and has the value
  before `\section`. The new version resets the counters transitively, that means, `subsubsection` is also reset as part of the reset action of `subsection`. Now `subsubsection` is also reset and is 0 right after `\section`.

Disadvantages:

- The transitivity has the risk for loops, the following document runs into such a loop and will therefore break:

  ```
  \documentclass{book}
  \makeatletter
  \@addtoreset{chapter}{footnote}
  \makeatother
  \begin{document}
  \chapter{foo} 
  \end{document}
  ```
- Other packages, which hook into `\stepcounter` like `zref-perpage` do not know, that this `\stepcounter` is not caused by an entity, thus `zref-perpage` thinks that there  is a `footnote` at the start of the chapter, a total of four footnotes, instead of three in the MWE of the question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am still wondering why my minimal working example worked before changes were made to LaTeX kernel ... ?

Comment: @user81070 See updated answer.

Comment: Hmm, so was this change made in error?

Comment: A similar problem came up last year (then with fixltx2e): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208605/new-fixltx2e-bigfoot-conflict